# c# send email through work mail

Tags: c#, email

I tried to write c# code to send emails through my work mail account.
I already connected the email account to my android smartphone and it's working well. I took the connection data from it and now  I'm trying to send email with c# but I can't manage it.
I used the same c# code to send email from my gmail account and it work fine, but when I try to use it with my work account I can't.
Am I doing something wrong?

My code is:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("myPersonalEmailAddress"));
mail.From = new MailAddress("myWorkEmailAddress");
mail.Subject = "Test subject";
mail.Body = "Test body";

/*
 * The server name, port and domain are similar to smartphone account
 * It also uses SSL so I enabled it
 */
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("serverName", 443);
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Timeout = 20000;

try
{
     client.Send(mail);
}

catch (Exception e)
{

}
```

Comment: `catch (Exception e) { }` won't help finding problems?

Comment: This post http://techiespider.com/2010/08/02/send-email-in-c-sharp-using-gmail/ does the very same things, I think your work somehow block this ports or something.

Comment: @Arjan I catch the exception and sometimes I get timeout and sometimes can't send email

Comment: I find it hard to believe you'd only get *"can't send email"*. Remove the `try` and its `catch` to see as much error information you can get.

Comment: @0x90 I'm connected to my work email account in my phone and it work fine, so maybe I'll try to do hotspot from my phone and try it?

Comment: And if that really doesn't reveal anything, then maybe you'd first have to [try manually using Telnet](http://superuser.com/questions/207926/if-to-and-from-headers-are-the-spammers-email-address-how-did-i-get-this-e/208156#208156), to see what the server responds.

Comment: @Arjan I get: The operation has timed out

Comment: Looks like a network problem, then, not a code problem.

Comment: Are you sure you are on the same network with both laptop and phone? and how do you run c# code on your mobile?

Comment: @0x90 I'm not on the same network. I run c# from VS2012 from my laptop, and my phone is on cellular network. So if I'll do hotspot with my phone and I'll connect to it from my laptop...

Comment: Uhuh, Yaniv, you're a programmer, why not try the steps from that link...? (Skip the first step; you already know which SMTP server you'll want to test.)

Comment: @Arjan I used telnet and it seems to be working ok, I get no errors, I get only blank screen

Comment: If you see a blank screen, then it's not working. Also, you should get responses to the commands you type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should make allow access for this in your gmail account then it will work fine

Comment: The Gmail accounts works, the work account does not. (The latter might be a Google App account, but Gmail works, the question claims.)

Comment: Ah, you might be right: maybe the Gmail connection data (server name) is used?

Comment: So, Yaniv, are you using the Gmail server settings for your work account?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you want me to do

Comment: @Yaniv, Gmail does not allow you to send email from another Sender address, unless you add that Sender address to your Gmail account. So, *if* you're using the Gmail servers to send messages with your work email address as the Sender, then you need to change something in Gmail to allow for that. But if you're using your work's SMTP server to send messages using your work email address, then the above answer does not apply.

Comment: @Arjan I'm not using Gmail to send from my work address. I want to use my work's SMTP server.

Comment: I gave up trying to connect to my work's SMTP server, I just couldn't do it. I don't know if it's a block of something else. So eventually I decided to use Gmail servers and to be honest this is a very easy way to do that :) Thanks everyone